# How to access integer and string of enum type?

Tags: c#, .net, string, enums

What C# code would output the following for a variable of the enum type below?

> Dentist (2533)

```
public enum eOccupationCode
        {
             Butcher = 2531,
             Baker = 2532,
             Dentist = 2533,
             Podiatrist = 2534,
             Surgeon = 2535,
             Other = 2539
        }
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also use the [format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/a0h36syw.aspx) `g`, `G`, `f`, `F` to print the name of the enumeration entry, or `d` and `D` to print the decimal representation:

```
var dentist = eOccupationCode.Dentist;

Console.WriteLine(dentist.ToString("G"));     // Prints: "Dentist"
Console.WriteLine(dentist.ToString("D"));     // Prints: "2533"
```

... or as handy one-liner:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:G} ({0:D})", dentist);  // Prints: "Dentist (2533)"
```

This works with `Console.WriteLine`, just as with `String.Format`.

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you want something like:

```
// Please drop the "e" prefix...
OccupationCode code = OccupationCode.Dentist;

string text = string.Format("{0} ({1})", code, (int) code);
```

Comment: Yeah he should really drop the "e" prefix

Answer (score 1):

`What C# code would output the following for a variable of the enum type below?`

Without casting, it would output the enum identifier: `Dentist`

If you need to access that enum value you need to cast it:

```
int value = (int)eOccupationCode.Dentist;
```

Comment: Can you help explain why this is the default and using the enum value is not the default?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean this

```
eOccupationCode code = eOccupationCode.Dentist;
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} ({1})", code,(int)code));
// outputs Dentist (2533)
```

Comment: The ToString is redundant.